# how do i connect my php to mysql for an ajax query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make this page sortable with a simple drop down. Right now there are only two different car makes in there and its not sorting those. I would like to be able to sort through make, model, and year, but need to figure this first part out first (right?).

Can somebody please help me out with this? Is there something wrong with my PHP code or my script or both?

```
<script>
function showCars(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("showcars").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getcars.php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<form>
<select name="make" onchange="showCars(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="Ford">Ford</option>
<option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="showcars">
<?php
$q = intval($_POST['q']);$con=mysqli_connect("mysql.database.com","user","password","table");
// Check connection
if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }

 mysqli_select_db($con,"ford_man");
 $sql="SELECT * FROM make WHERE make = '".$q."'";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {

  echo '<span style="float: left; wdith="300px;">' . $row['pics']  . '</span>';
  echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;' . '<span style="font-size:28px;">' . $row['year'] .    '</span>';  echo "&nbsp;"; echo '<span style="font-size:28px;">' . $row['make'] . '</span>'; echo "&nbsp;"; echo '<span style="font-size:28px;">' . $row['model'] . '</span>';
  echo "<br>"; 
  echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;' . '<span style="font-size:32px;">' . $row['price'] . '</span>'; echo "&nbsp; &nbsp;"; echo '<span style="font-size: 26px;">' . $row['miles'] . '</span>'; echo "&nbsp;";  echo 'miles' ;
  echo "<br>";
  echo '<span style="width:800px; float:left;">' . $row['description'] . '</span>';
  echo "<br>";
  echo '<i> &nbsp; &nbsp;'; echo '<span style="font-size:12px;">' .  'Stock#' . '</span>';   echo '&nbsp;'; echo '<span style="font-size:12px;">' . $row['stock'] . '</span>'; echo'</i>';
  echo '<br>'; 
  echo '<br>';
  echo '<br>';
  echo '<a style="text-decoration: none; color: rgba(254,094,008,1.00);"   href="mailto:agustus64050@yahoo.com">' . 'Email Me About This Car' . '</a>';
  echo "<hr>";
 }
  mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: In the `mysqli_connect` table is actually supposed to be database, unless your database is named table.

Answer (score 1):

In your AJAX you're using GET whereas your php is looking in the POST superglobal

Comment: i have tried that and i always get this error on the page http://www.havikmarketing.com/images/error.png

Comment: I guess I should say that my first field "id" is null and auto inc . . . so i'm not sure if that's why i get the error . . . there is no 1

Comment: I believe the comment from MrHunter might be the solution to your problem. Try changing "table" with "ford_man" assuming that this is the name of your DB and also make sure that your table name is indeed "make" because it seems you are using the same name both for the table and for one of its columns.